# GSON ignore elements with wrong type

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit (in combination with OkHttp and GSON) to communicate with an online webservice.
The webservice has a default wrapper around all it's responses, similar to:

```
{  
  "resultCode":"OK",
  "resultObj":"Can be a string or JSON object / array",
  "error":"",
  "message":""
}
```

In this example `resultCode` will either be `OK` or `NO`. Furthermore `error` and `message` only have any contents when an error has occured while processing the request. And last, but not least, `resultObj` will contain the actual result from the call (which is a string in the example, but some calls return a JSON array or a JSON object).

To process this meta data, I created a generic class, like this one:

```java
public class ApiResult<T> {

    private String error;
    private String message;
    private String resultCode;
    private T resultObj;

    // + some getters, setters etcetera
}
```

I've also created classes that represent the responses sometimes given in `resultObj` and I've defined an interface for use with Retrofit, that looks a bit like this:

```java
public interface SomeWebService {

    @GET("/method/string")
    ApiResult<String> someCallThatReturnsAString();

    @GET("/method/pojo")
    ApiResult<SomeMappedResult> someCallThatReturnsAnObject();

}
```

As long as the request is valid this all works fine. But when an error occurs on the server side, it will still return a `resultObj` with a String-type. This causes `someCallThatReturnsAnObject` to crash inside the Retrofit RestAdapter / GSON library, with a message like this:

> retrofit.RetrofitError:
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>
> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 110 path $.resultObj

Now, finally, my questions are:

1. Is there an (easy) way to tell GSON that it should just ignore (aka "nullify") a property if it does not match the expected type?
2. Can I tell GSON to treat empty strings as null?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Define your model like this:

```
public class ApiResult {

    private String error;
    private String message;
    private String resultCode;
    private MyResultObject resultObj;
}
```

Then, create a **TypeAdapterFactory** for **MyResultObject**:

```
public class MyResultObjectAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (type.getRawType()!= MyResultObject.class) return null;

        TypeAdapter<MyResultObject> defaultAdapter = (TypeAdapter<MyResultObject>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new MyResultObjectAdapter(defaultAdapter);
    }

    public class MyResultObjectAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MyResultObject> {

        protected TypeAdapter<MyResultObject> defaultAdapter;


        public MyResultObjectAdapter(TypeAdapter<MyResultObject> defaultAdapter) {
            this.defaultAdapter = defaultAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, MyResultObject value) throws IOException {
            defaultAdapter.write(out, value);
        }

        @Override
        public MyResultObject read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            /* 
            This is the critical part. So if the value is a string,
            Skip it (no exception) and return null.
            */
            if (in.peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
                in.skipValue();
                return null;
            }
            return defaultAdapter.read(in);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, register **MyResultObjectAdapterFactory** for **Gson**:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new MyResultObjectAdapterFactory())
    .create();
```

Now, when deserializing an **ApiResult** json with that *Gson* object, *resultObj* will be set **null** if it is a *string*.

I Hope this solves your problem =)

Comment: so how do you get the String out of resultObj?

Comment: it works but what if we have several beans that require this kind of fix? Should we implement again and again this adapter, which will be lot of duplicate code?

Answer (score 11):

I've had a similar problem and came up with the following solution in the end:

In stead of trying to parse your element into a `String` or `Array`, try storing the data to a simple java.lang.Object

This prevents the parsing from crashing or throwing an exception.

eg. with GSON annotations the property of your model would look like this:

```
@SerializedName("resultObj")
@Expose
private java.lang.Object resultObj;
```

Next, when accessing your data at runtime, you can check if your `resultObj` property is an instance of `String` or not.

```
if(apiResultObject instanceof String ){
    //Cast to string and do stuff

} else{
    //Cast to array and do stuff

}
```

Original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178082/3708094

Comment: Thanks.Helped me.Easiest way to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

First, this is a bad API design that you're dealing with. :-(

You can use a custom [JsonDeserializer](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/gson-1.7.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) to handle this case.

Register it with Retrofit:

```
MyJsonDeserializer deserializer = new MyJsonDeserializer()).create();
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ApiResult.class, deserializer);
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(API_URL)
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .build();
```

Comment: Are you sure that this will work with the generic class? In the past I had troubles with GSON and custom deserializers for generic classes.

PS: I know it's a bad design, but unfortunately, I have no say in what happens with the webservice.

Comment: Not sure on generics, actually. Only one way to find out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm reusing my reponse pojo.

In one response it's `String` and another response it's `List<MajicalModel> magicalField` so one parsing failed.

I change it to `com.google.gson.JsonElement magicalField;` it's work for me. This way it parse raw json and also ignore type mismatch.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code as well:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
yourObject = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, <ClassName>.class);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is related to GSON, not Jackson?