# how to solve com.google.gson.JsonException: java IllegalStateException :Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was String at line 1 coulmn 10

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I got this code from a referenced site for getting twitter feeds in a list , but i am getting an error of JsonException as mentioned above
please need some help in solving the error

```
public class TwitterAPI {
private String twitterApiKey;
private String twitterAPISecret;
final static String TWITTER_TOKEN_URL =
"https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
final static String TWITTER_STREAM_URL =
"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";

public TwitterAPI(String twitterAPIKey, String twitterApiSecret) {
    this.twitterApiKey = twitterAPIKey;
    this.twitterAPISecret = twitterApiSecret;
}

public ArrayList<TwitterTweet> getTwitterTweets(String screenName) {
    ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweetArrayList = null;
    try {
        String twitterUrlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(twitterApiKey, "UTF-8");
        String twitterUrlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(twitterAPISecret,
        "UTF-8");
        String twitterKeySecret = twitterUrlApiKey + ":" +
        twitterUrlApiSecret;
        String twitterKeyBase64 =
        Base64.encodeToString(twitterKeySecret.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        TwitterAuthToken twitterAuthToken =
        getTwitterAuthToken(twitterKeyBase64);
        twitterTweetArrayList = getTwitterTweets(screenName,
        twitterAuthToken);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex1) {
    }
    return twitterTweetArrayList;
}

public ArrayList<TwitterTweet> getTwitterTweets(String screenName,
TwitterAuthToken twitterAuthToken) {
    ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweetArrayList = null;
    if (twitterAuthToken != null &&
        twitterAuthToken.token_type.equals("bearer")) {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TWITTER_STREAM_URL + screenName);
        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +
        twitterAuthToken.access_token);
        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();
        String twitterTweets = httpUtil.getHttpResponse(httpGet);
        twitterTweetArrayList = convertJsonToTwitterTweet(twitterTweets);
    }
    return twitterTweetArrayList;
}

public TwitterAuthToken getTwitterAuthToken(String twitterKeyBase64) throws
UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TWITTER_TOKEN_URL);
    httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + twitterKeyBase64);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-
    urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
    HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();
    String twitterJsonResponse = httpUtil.getHttpResponse(httpPost);
    return convertJsonToTwitterAuthToken(twitterJsonResponse);
}

private TwitterAuthToken convertJsonToTwitterAuthToken(String jsonAuth) {
    TwitterAuthToken twitterAuthToken = null;
    if (jsonAuth != null && jsonAuth.length() > 0) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            twitterAuthToken = gson.fromJson(jsonAuth,
            TwitterAuthToken.class);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        }
    }
    return twitterAuthToken;
}

private ArrayList<TwitterTweet> convertJsonToTwitterTweet(String  
twitterTweets) {
    ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweetArrayList = null;
    if (twitterTweets != null && twitterTweets.length() > 0) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            twitterTweetArrayList = gson.fromJson(twitterTweets, new
            TypeToken<ArrayList<TwitterTweet>>() {
            }.getType());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        }
    }
    return twitterTweetArrayList;
}

private class TwitterAuthToken {
    String token_type;
    String access_token;
}
```

LogCat :

> 02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   AsyncTask #1 02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() 02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) 02-12 12:10:27.684:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239) 02-12
>   12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 02-12
>   12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864) 02-12 12:10:27.684:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30448): Caused by:
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 10 02-12
>   12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):    at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:180)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755) 02-12 12:10:27.684:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:721) 02-12 12:10:27.684:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:670) 02-12 12:10:27.684:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:642) 02-12 12:10:27.684:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.app.movie_name_rating.TwitterAPI.convertJsonToTwitterAuthToken(TwitterAPI.java:70)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.app.movie_name_rating.TwitterAPI.getTwitterAuthToken(TwitterAPI.java:62)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.app.movie_name_rating.TwitterAPI.getTwitterTweets(TwitterAPI.java:34)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.app.movie_name_rating.TwitterAsyncTask.doInBackground(TwitterAsyncTask.java:22) 02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.app.movie_name_rating.TwitterAsyncTask.doInBackground(TwitterAsyncTask.java:1)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 02-12 12:10:27.684:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 02-12
>   12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):    ... 4 more 02-12 12:10:27.684:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30448): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 10 02-12
>   12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):    at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:339) 02-12
>   12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):    at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:322)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:168)
>   02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448):  ... 15 more

Comment: First log your response and check if you are getting correct value.

Comment: I wrote a solution to this problem.

See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31604097/2749361

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for the solution here it is:

1) First and foremost important thing is to replace the API secret and API key with your own generated ones.

2) The exception is coming because the API Key and API secret is not replaced and hence it is failing at Line- 70 as per the logcat output above:--

```
    com.app.movie_name_rating.TwitterAPI.convertJsonToTwitterAuthToken(TwitterAPI.java:70) 02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448): at 
com.app.movie_name_rating.TwitterAPI.getTwitterAuthToken(TwitterAPI.java:62) 02-12 12:10:27.684: E/AndroidRuntime(30448): at
```

Instead of returning a valid JSON string with valid Access token in the format below--

```
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANOmuQAAAAAAeIchMrbQdzP09sNyZYAtJQsLZ3k%3DhZuwbNpKTgHdvbhLS7ud3EdIUxz7iqZQyoAL4JhpBSf5tgEnTC"}
```

it is returning a String `Forbidden` which is not in valid JSON format.

So ideally you need to handle this case in exception instead of simply eating the exception  in the following code piece which is a bad practice.

```
catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        }
```