# Retrofit 2, parsing json, ignore wrong data type inside array

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

i'm trying to parse a response json from server. the data is an array of objects, but some times server send an boolean between items of array. like this:

```
{
    "msg_code": 200,
    "msg_type": "success",
    "msg_text": "success",
    "msg_data": [
        {
            "pid": "1234567",
            "time": "1459029423",
            "parent_pid": "0"
        },
        false,
        {
            "pid": "987654",
            "time": "1458997403",
            "parent_pid": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see there is a **false** between them.

when i try to parse these the the converter reach the wrong data type and throw an exception like these:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 9988 path $.msg_data[12]
```

so how can i skip this wrong datatype and continue to parse other elements?

this is my code for creating Retrofit client:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(logLevel);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        gooderApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_API_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
                .create(ApiInterface.class);
```

i searched alot and i know i must create a custom converter factory, but all the example are old and belongs to Retrofit < 2, and i don't know how to make them work for me.

**Update:**
similar question:
[GSON ignore elements with wrong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212598/gson-ignore-elements-with-wrong-type)

tnx in advance.

Comment: @DanielK where i can do that? retrofit do all the work.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this question, did you update your POJO schema to the one posted in the responses?

Comment: yes, my POJO class is fully functional, if that BOOLEAN is't there. my parser works fine when the data type is right. this is a special case that sometimes server put a BOOLEAN inside the array and make my parse break.

Comment: You did better than I did, I could not find good references for this problem after all this time. I know this is a workaround but would you consider, since this only happens sometimes, redoing the API call in the exception block? It may be easier than creating a custom deserializer.

Comment: What do you mean by `redoing the API call in the exception block?`

Comment: Well you're using RxJava so you would redo your API call again in `onError(Throwable e);`. It's a workaround but it may work for you. Also did you try the first solution? The one where they just save it as an object and then check the instance at runtime.

Comment: I see your point, but the error is persistent for some parameter in request. in this case if i call my api inside `onError` it fall into an infinite loop.

Comment: I see, try the first solution before implementing the custom deserializer. I think it would look like `List<Object> msg_data = new ArrayList<Object>();`. According to that post, this will keep it from throwing an exception, then where necessary you would just check `(msg_data.get(i) instanceof Boolean)`

Comment: ok, if i  do that retrofit can not map the value. my class has all annotation for mapping values like `@SerializedName("pid")` but the `Object` has not and retrofit falls throw another error.

Comment: Try setting the type of msg_data as JsonObject

Answer (score 1):

Change call into `JSON Object` **OR** remove `false` in the server.

Retrofit didn't have solution for that i think.....

Bcoz `boolean` coming into the array of POJO object.

`Boolean` is just assign to **array of data**.

[image: json]

this is correct json have look

```
{
    "msg_code": 200,
    "msg_type": "success",
    "msg_text": "success",
    "msg_data": [
        {
            "pid": "1234567",
            "time": "1459029423",
            "parent_pid": "0"
        },
        false,
        {
            "pid": "987654",
            "time": "1458997403",
            "parent_pid": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

there is `,` after `"parent_pid": "0"` you have to remove it .

enjoy coding.........

Comment: sorry that was my fault, i just omitted some of data for making code brief. the actual problem is that BOOLEAN.

Comment: it is not valid for my class, you suggest to set the response type to `Object`, i have my custom class. please look at the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Json` is invalid, remove `,` from

```
"parent_pid": "0"
```

Try to use [Json formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/),[JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and other sites to check whether `JsonObject` is correct or not.

Comment: sorry that was my fault, i just omitted some of data for making code brief. the actual problem is that BOOLEAN.

Comment: yes that boolean should not be there, you should use `JsonObject` inside `JsonArray`

Comment: the data is from 3rd party server and i can not fix it, i need to address this issue in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Put your JSON data into [Json Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr) to check your JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the , check the json like this:

```
{
    "msg_code": 200,
    "msg_type": "success",
    "msg_text": "success",
    "msg_data": [
        {
            "pid": "1234567",
            "time": "1459029423",
            "parent_pid": "0"
        },
        false,
        {
            "pid": "987654",
            "time": "1458997403",
            "parent_pid": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

After converting your json to Pojo your Pojo class look like this:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@SerializedName("msg_code")
@Expose
private Integer msgCode;
@SerializedName("msg_type")
@Expose
private String msgType;
@SerializedName("msg_text")
@Expose
private String msgText;
@SerializedName("msg_data")
@Expose
private List<MsgDatum> msgData = new ArrayList<MsgDatum>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The msgCode
*/
public Integer getMsgCode() {
return msgCode;
}

/**
* 
* @param msgCode
* The msg_code
*/
public void setMsgCode(Integer msgCode) {
this.msgCode = msgCode;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The msgType
*/
public String getMsgType() {
return msgType;
}

/**
* 
* @param msgType
* The msg_type
*/
public void setMsgType(String msgType) {
this.msgType = msgType;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The msgText
*/
public String getMsgText() {
return msgText;
}

/**
* 
* @param msgText
* The msg_text
*/
public void setMsgText(String msgText) {
this.msgText = msgText;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The msgData
*/
public List<MsgDatum> getMsgData() {
return msgData;
}

/**
* 
* @param msgData
* The msg_data
*/
public void setMsgData(List<MsgDatum> msgData) {
this.msgData = msgData;
}

}
```

Comment: sorry, the `,` was a typo.

Comment: Check your webservice properly whether you need the boolean or not?If not discard it.

Comment: i dont need that, the problem is HOW to skip it?

Comment: you can't skip the response type while parsing it,you have to change your webservice according to your need.

Comment: i the below question they have a way with creating custom converter, i just need to adopt that to my situation, but i dont know how.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212598/gson-ignore-elements-with-wrong-type

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJson);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("msg_data");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                if (jsonArray.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                } else {
                    Boolean b = jsonArray.getBoolean(i);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: this works if i manually parse the json, but i'm using retrofit. how can i adopt this to retrofit? 
similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212598/gson-ignore-elements-with-wrong-type