# Retrofit (Android): How to properly process wrong data types in response?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am wondering how this issue is properly solved because it affects everyone using Retrofit:

If i define field type as **Integer scale** and normally I get **scale: 7** in JSON response then everything looks good. But if server suddenly returns **scale: 0.56** or **scale: null** or **scale: N/A**  I get an exception -> app crash.

I could convert all fields to String in Java code but that kind of removes the sense of using Retrofit.

Pls. do not reply like "just fix your server". It's all about stability - the app must not crash regardless of server' response.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212598/gson-ignore-elements-with-wrong-type

Comment: Thanks, this could do the trick. (I'm still puzzled why it's not a built-in functionality in Retrofit. Finally, one would take some library to make programming easier, and if one has to write workarounds for basic things by himself ...)